# What can I do if I want to access settings.py in Windows 7 and it doesn't open?

Tags: django, settings

I'm using the tutorial for a Django project and follow their instructions, but once I try to open settings.py to make changes, the setting don't open. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does that even mean, it won't open? You can't open the file? Right click -> open with?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean open `settings.py` for editing/ viewing code?

If that's the case, then it's likely that `*.py` files have been associated with the Python interpreter and not an editor. That means double-clicking the file will run the file. To avoid this, simply open the editor first, then use it to open the file.

If it's not the case, then you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: Ok the case is, im trying to edit some of the settings like DATABASES_ENGINE but when i try to edit it it doesnt show me the menu settings.py main.py __init__.py

Comment: If this is the official Django tutorial, then it's showing you a listing of the files that are created, not a menu. The `settings.py` file is a text file with a `.py` extension instead of `.txt`. Open `settings.py` with a simple text editor.